# Abrir aquivo .py no terminal do VsCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Estou começando a estudar python (primeira linguagem) e acabei de instalar o VsCode (antes usava o Pycharm). Estou apanhando muito com as configurações do Code.

Antes eu conseguia abrir o meu script (main.py) direto do terminal, apenas digitando ".\main.py". Automaticamente o script rodava no terminal mesmo.
*considerando que eu já esteja dentro da pasta do projeto.

Mas acabei desconfigurando alguma coisa e agora quando eu tento rodar o script via commando, abre uma janela externa do python.exe

Como eu faço para voltar a configuração anterior e abrir o script dentro do próprio terminal?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial
Acho que tem o que você precisa

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Mas no material que me enviou diz que tenho que digitar no terminal "python nomedoarquivo.py", ok... isso funciona perfeitamente. Mas porque antes funcionava sem digitar "python" no começo? Tem alguma forma de não precisar digitar "python"?